# What can I power my cropnalyzer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

It works of batteries, but the fourth analysis takes up a whole battery, making it rather tedious to cropnalyze many crops. I tried a lapotronic crystal and that didn't work. Is it just batteries or is there something more powerful I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't accept Lapotrons for some unknown reason, but it does support Energy crystals. So use those.